# Check if a certain value exist in the passed parameter in query (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql, sql-server, report, conditional-statements

So I need to determine if a certain value exist in the passed parameter to perform a certain condition. Here's the query below:

```
DECLARE @PCStatusas varchar(50);

SELECT * FROM 
Employee emp 
WHERE (emp.PCStatus IN (@PCStatus) OR @PCStatus = '') 
OR
```

> ('ON-HOLD' IN (@PCStatus)

```
AND CAST(emp.EffectiveDate AS DATE) <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
```

so what i need is to check if the parameter sent contain the value 'ON-HOLD' to perform the EffectiveDate condition being equal or less than today.

Comment: since you are using `IN` I suspect the `@PCStatusas` is a comma separated string. If so, your `IN` clause isn't going to work. You'll need to use a string splitter or better yet, a table values parameter

Comment: can you please verify and re-format your query properly. Example is it suppose to be `@PCStatusas` or `DECLARE @PCStatus as varchar(50);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like `(@PCStatus like '%ON-HOLD%')`

```
DECLARE @PCStatusas varchar(50);

SELECT * FROM 
Employee emp 
WHERE (emp.PCStatus IN (@PCStatus) OR @PCStatus = '') 
OR 
(@PCStatus like '%ON-HOLD%')

AND CAST(emp.EffectiveDate AS DATE) <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
```

Comment: This could work however it only applies on a string csv. If I apply this on a wide variety of integer csv, the result will differ.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mix `AND` and `OR` conditions, it is best to use parenthesis `( )` on it to clearly define the intended conditions.

Also avoid applying function on the column as it will prohibit the use of index on the column. If the EffectiveDate does not contain time, you may simply use equal `emp.EffectiveDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` else you should use `>= today` and  `< tomorrow`

```
DECLARE @PCStatus as varchar(50);

SELECT * 
FROM   Employee emp 
WHERE  
(
       emp.PCStatus       = @PCStatus
)
OR     
(
       @PCStatus          = ''
)
OR 
(
       @PCStatus          LIKE '%ON-HOLD%'
AND    emp.EffectiveDate >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
AND    emp.EffectiveDate <  CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
)
```

EDIT : change to `LIKE '%ON-HOLD%'`

EDIT 2 : @PCStatus is CSV
here, the query is using `STRING_SPLIT()` if you are using earlier version of SQL Server, use the `DelimitedSplit8K` that i posted in the comments

```
DECLARE @PCStatus as varchar(50) = 'ACTIVE,ON-HOLD';

SELECT * 
FROM   Employee emp 
WHERE  
(
    @PCStatus          = ''
OR  EXISTS
    (
        select  *
        from    STRING_SPLIT(@PCStatus, ',') x
        where   x.value     = emp.PCStatus
    )
)
AND 
(
    emp.PCStatus      <> 'ON-HOLD'
OR  emp.EffectiveDate <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. However this didn't provide any answer in identifying if the parameter holds the "ON-HOLD" value.

Comment: `@PCStatus` is a CSV ? or single value ? Please provide some sample data and expected result. Else we can only guess what you want

Comment: We'll i thought that the structure of my query gives away that PCStatus is a csv. 
"ON-HOLD, ACTIVE, SUSPENDED" are the possible values of PCStatus and yes they can be submitted altogether or without the other.

Answer (score 0):

So with the help of my colleague, we created a function that splits the csv into a temporary table and there I can simply check if a certain value is in the temporary table and return a Boolean for it. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: if you are using `SQL Server 2016` or later you can use `STRING_SPLIT()`. If not, this is the best around http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/